# How can I find Ignite nodes that aren't actively computing a Job?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using Ignite 2.13 in a Windows environment.
I have exclusive use of a 110 node compute grid.  I want to complete a ComputeTask that maps to 100 ComputeJobs.  The jobs take a variable amount of time to complete.  As the compute progresses many of the nodes become idle waiting for the remaining jobs to complete.   Midway through the compute I'd like to find all the idle nodes and then kill some subset of them, leaving a few in case one of the remaining jobs randomly fails and needs to failover.

In the ComputeTask the "result" method is called as Jobs complete.  From the "result" method I'm trying to find all the grid nodes with an active job.  Any node that does not have an active job is assumed idle and potentially eligible to be killed off.

I have two methods for finding the nodes with an active job getActiveNodesOld and getActiveNodesLocal.  They return drastically different answers.

```
// This version uses this node's view of the all the cluster.
// This status lags behind reality by 2 seconds.
public static Collection<UUID> getActiveNodesOld(Ignite grid)
{
    Set<UUID> retval = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    Collection<ClusterNode> nodes = grid.cluster().nodes();
    for(ClusterNode node : nodes)
    {
        int activeJobs = node.metrics().getCurrentActiveJobs();
        if(activeJobs > 0)
        {
            retval.add(node.id());
        }
    }
    
    return retval;
}

// This version asks each node about its own status.  The results are supposed to be more
// accurate.

public static Collection<UUID> getActiveNodesLocal(Ignite grid)
{
    Set<UUID> retval = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    IgniteCompute compute = grid.compute();

    Collection<IgniteBiTuple<UUID, Integer>> metricsMap =
            compute.broadcast(new ActiveJobCallable());

    for(Map.Entry<UUID, Integer> entry : metricsMap)
    {
        UUID id = entry.getKey();
        int activeJobs = entry.getValue();

        if(activeJobs > 0)
        {
            retval.add(id);
        }
        if(activeJobs > 1){
            logger.info("Warning: Node:" + id + " has " + activeJobs + " active jobs. ");
        }
    }

    return retval;
}

private static class ActiveJobCallable implements IgniteCallable<IgniteBiTuple<UUID, Integer>>
{

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private transient Ignite ignite;


    public ActiveJobCallable()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public IgniteBiTuple<UUID, Integer> call()
    {
        ClusterNode clusterNode = ignite.cluster().localNode();
        ClusterMetrics nodeMetrics = clusterNode.metrics();

        return new IgniteBiTuple<>(clusterNode.id(), nodeMetrics.getCurrentActiveJobs());
    }
}
```

These two methods return very different results with regard to which nodes are active.  The first time through the getActiveNodesLocal reports that there are 0 active nodes.  I can see how this is possible - perhaps a job is not considered complete until "result" returns.  I'll give it the benefit of the doubt.  The other method, getActiveNodesOld indicates there is a large number of idle nodes. Even though its being called for the first completed compute job so the remainder of the grid should still be working on compute jobs.
As the compute progresses neither method produces the answers I'd expect.  The nodes seem to start reporting 1 activeJob and then never report 0 activeJobs even after the job is complete.  Do I need to be resetting the ClusterMetrics somehow?

The method getActiveNodesLocal broadcasts an IgniteCallable into the grid.  Does that callable get counted in the results of getCurrentActiveJobs()?  It doesn't seem to but I thought that might explain the weird results I'm seeing.  I never see the logger message I added that should be triggered if "activeJobs > 1".

Is there some other way I Should accomplish my goal of finding nodes that are idling?  Can I find, for example, what node each job is currently assigned to and then determine which nodes don't have a job assignment?  I don't see a method for the ComputeTask to determine node<->job mapping but maybe I'm just overlooking it.

I suppose I could have the nodes send a grid message when they start and also when they complete a job and I could track which jobs are active but that feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: I was able to determine that I wasn't seeing the answers I was expecting b/c the remote jobs were not running when I was expecting them to run.  Free nodes would respond immediately, busy nodes would not respond until their current compute job was complete.  Probably not an error in Ignite but a misunderstanding on my part.  The cache method below is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Skip ClusterMetrics entirely.  Create an IgniteCache and put the node UUID in the cache when the Job is started and remove the UUID when the job is completed.

Finding the Nodes that are still in the cluster and have a job could be done like this:

```
public static Collection<UUID> getActiveNodesCache(Ignite grid)
{
    Set<UUID> retval = new TreeSet<>();
    IgniteCache<UUID, ComputeJob> workingOnMap = grid.cache(JOB_CACHE); 

    workingOnMap.query(new ScanQuery<>(null)).forEach(entry -> retval.add((UUID) entry.getKey()));
    // We count on the nodes to add and remove themselves from the cache when they start/complete jobs.
    // Nodes that crashed aren't removed from this cache - they just die.  So retval could
    // contain nodes that are gone at this point.


    Set<UUID> inGrid = grid.cluster().nodes().stream().map(ClusterNode::id).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<UUID> notInGrid = new LinkedHashSet<>(retval);
    notInGrid.removeAll(inGrid);

    retval.retainAll(inGrid);   // remove any nodes that are no longer in the cluster.

    logger.log(Level.INFO,
            "Found {0} nodes in grid.  {1} of those are active.  {2} nodes were active but left grid.",
            new Object[]{inGrid.size(), retval.size(), notInGrid.size()});

    return retval;
}
```

The ComputeJobs can create the cache like this:

```
IgniteCache<UUID, ComputeJob> workingOnMap = grid.getOrCreateCache(getInProgressConfig());
```

Because you want to kill the nodes, be sure the cache is REPLICATED across the grid so that dead nodes don't take portions of the cache with them.

```
public static CacheConfiguration<UUID, ComputeJob> getInProgressConfig()
    {
        CacheConfiguration<UUID, ComputeJob> config = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        config.setName(JOB_CACHE);
        config.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        config.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        config.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
     
        return config;
    }
```